# How to increase timeout from url function

Tags: r

How to increase the timeout time from the url function in the base package?

I am trying:

```
options(timeout = 200)
url( Link, open = "r" ,  timeout = getOption("timeout"))
```

But it does not work, the timeout is the same and returns the next error:

```
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'the operation timed out'
```

The link activates a process that takes some time and I would like to avoid that error message in order to get the logs. I tried also the RCurl package with the function geturl but it does not fit in this case because is asking for credentials while base::url dont need.

I am running R version 3.4.1. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try ```httr``` too!

Comment: It asks for credentials too. For security reasons you need user and password, but from my computer in a browser I do not need to introduce it. Thats why RCurl or httr fails, but base::url not. The timeout is an issue tho

Comment: You can pass credentials with `httr`. I do not think you fully understand what's happening.

Comment: Yes but, its not exactly a problem of adding pw or user, which would go automatically in my computer. It looks like when it request the host to ask for validation to the page, it returns a NULL and so, the access is denied. It is an informatic problem and I dont understand why it happens. With base::url I dont have this problem, but the time out is not enough. If I introduce the url in a browser it works fine, I am just trying to automate it with R since it is part of a script that will use some of that information. The webpage loads some data in database in function of args contained in link

Answer (score 0):

I've used the function:

```
 curlSetOpt(timeout = 2000)
```

which solved this issue for me